# Why parseInt on a variable using expression does not display $scope variable?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, scope

Here is my code,

**WORKING CODE**

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller("ListCtrl", ["$scope",
  function($scope) {
         $scope.value = '20';
  }
]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.7" data-semver="1.4.7" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
   <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app='app'>
  <div ng-controller="ListCtrl">
   <h1> {{value}}</h1>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**NOT WORKING CODE:**

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller("ListCtrl", ["$scope",
  function($scope) {
         $scope.value = '20';
  }
]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.7" data-semver="1.4.7" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
   <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app='app'>
  <div ng-controller="ListCtrl">
   <h1> {{parseInt(value)}}</h1>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Normally using parseInt on an expression should work, what is the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to parse the value in the controller since angular is not able to `parseInt` into an Angular expression:

In the other hand if you really want to make this in the DOM one of the best options is to use an angular filter like:

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.filter('parseInt', function() {
    return function(value) {
      return parseInt(value);
    };
});

app.controller("ListCtrl", ["$scope",
  function($scope) {
         $scope.value = '20';
  }
]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.7" data-semver="1.4.7" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
   <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app='app'>
  <div ng-controller="ListCtrl">
   <h1>{{(value | parseInt) + 44}}</h1>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the doc

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression

Angular does not use JavaScript's eval() to evaluate expressions. Instead Angular's $parse service processes these expressions.

For the question about why it does not display check this

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/interpolation

if the interpolated value is not a String, it is computed as follows:

**undefined** and null are converted to ''

Since ParseInt in not available inside interpolation, it is undefined and so is the displayed value.

you will have to create your own function in the controller $scope.

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller("ListCtrl", ["$scope",function($scope) {
  
         $scope.value = '20';
  
         $scope.parseInt = function(value)
         {
           return parseInt(value);
         }
         
      
         
  }
]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.7" data-semver="1.4.7" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
   <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app='app'>
  <div ng-controller="ListCtrl">
   <h1> {{parseInt(value)}}</h1>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```